# RaspberryPI OS in a GitHub release?

Tags: git, github, raspberry-pi, github-actions

Is there a way to use a github action to prepare a release that has rpi os, python, flask und rpi.gpio. So you can just download the release and put it on a sd card?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any documentation about it but this project is using a GitHub action to create a raspbian lite image by using pi-gen and adding a custom build step: https://www.github.com/hyperion-project/HyperBian/tree/master/.github%2Fworkflows%2Frelease.yml
I've used travis-ci to do the same for my raspberry project: https://www.github.com/Honey-Pi/HoneyPi-Build-Raspbian/tree/master/.travis.yml